# Verificar se um valor está contido na linha

Tags: mysql

Estou trabalhando com um sistema de consulta, e gostaria de que, por exemplo: Se eu procurar pelo valor "a", ele me retornasse todos as linhas que possuem "a".
Tentei usar o comando *like*, como mostrado abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome LIKE 'a%';
```

Mas ele só me retorna se o valor está no início da linha. Como posso verificar se "a" está contido na linha?

Comment: Não seria `'%a%`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O % é um *wildcard* que representa "qualquer coisa". Ou seja, a busca está sendo feita por nomes que iniciem com "a" e tenham **qualquer coisa depois**.

Só é preciso adaptar para **qualquer coisa antes e depois** de "a".

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nome LIKE '%a%';
```